# What happens if device sends data to arduino over serial port (UART) and arduino is unable to read it

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, uart

Suppose delay(10000) function is executed, so Arduino cannot do any other work.

> During this time if the other device sends the data to arduino what
>   will happen ?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the memory available, between 16 and 256 bytes will be stored in a ring buffer. Any bytes that arrive after that will be just thrown away.

The reception code in the core is:

```
void HardwareSerial::_rx_complete_irq(void)
{
  if (bit_is_clear(*_ucsra, UPE0)) {
    // No Parity error, read byte and store it in the buffer if there is
    // room
    unsigned char c = *_udr;
    rx_buffer_index_t i = (unsigned int)(_rx_buffer_head + 1) % SERIAL_RX_BUFFER_SIZE;

    // if we should be storing the received character into the location
    // just before the tail (meaning that the head would advance to the
    // current location of the tail), we're about to overflow the buffer
    // and so we don't write the character or advance the head.
    if (i != _rx_buffer_tail) {
      _rx_buffer[_rx_buffer_head] = c;
      _rx_buffer_head = i;
    }
  } else {
    // Parity error, read byte but discard it
    *_udr;
  };
}
```